# CakePHP 1.3: High CPU Usage

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, hosting, cpanel

I have a CakePHP application that is running on a shared hosting account, which the provider has been bugging me a lot (A2HOSTING) that my account is excessively using CPU resources, sometimes 100%.

Just on the last few hours alone, CPanel is reporting high CPU Usage. I have spoken with them and they said that everything is pointing to the 'webroot' directory. There I only have `index.php` and `css.php`.

Any ideas, what can be causing this issue, and what can I do to fix it, as they are threatening to suspend my account.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You aren't exactly giving us a lot to work with here. What is your application? How heavily is it being used? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi... this is the site.... www.bravanews.com . It is a news site, but NOT heavily visited as to cause this kind of problems. I have looked thru my code, but I can see anything that might be causing this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a whole lot to say without a more
information. For now, Let's start with what is using 100% cpu? MySQL or PHP?
Also, the conditions you use. Any associations and so on...

If it all works ok on your local setup then I would start by looking
at any differences between that and your server.
Versions of CakePHP, PHP, MySQL... are they different? Is the server
running some infamous version of one of them?

Let's blame the database:
Is the database structure and data really identical, really? Look
carefully as every detail.
Do you have the same content in them? Exactly? Clone your dev database
including all table definitions and data.

Sometimes I notice a lapse of logic on my part where a "clean"
database will cause problems because I have had data in it during the
whole development and for some reason I have missed that something
(seemingly unrelated) will fail if a table is empty.

Let's blame PHP:
When PHP ends up at 100% cpu, the problem is usually that it is stuck
in a loop somewhere. Do you have one near that line?
If you let the request run, do you just get a timeout or an out of
memory?

Finding "first" should never result in out of memory unless your
server
has 200'000 related records being loaded. Try specifying recursive -1.
That is: load absolutely nothing from any other table.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cake-php/lS91s355_Pw

[This post](http://www.sks.com.np/article/4/reduce-high-cpu-usage-overload-problem-caused-by-mysql.html) might help you to decrease the CPU overload.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking at all your suggestions and will post back with any result.

Comment: I looked thru everything I could without much luck. My application runs just fine in my development server, but my Host complains that it was taking too much of their shared CPU Time. It finally boiled over when they decided to limit my account to 1:15 seconds delay. I switched from A2HOSTING to GODADDY and now I have no problems. My cakephp site loads in 2 seconds. I am starting to believe A2HOSTING uses this as a sale push. I remember every time they complained about my CPU usage, they suggested buying their DEDICATED HOSTING PLAN. I didnt and I dont regret it. I will NEVER use them AGAIN!