# How to check high CPU usage CakePHP script with top

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, cakephp

It is convenient to check which PHP script is having high CPU usage by using command: top -c

The output would be like:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                         
22904 user  20   0  191m 9896 2156 R 12.9  0.6   0:01.25 /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/my_running_script.php
```

However, when I am using CakePHP framekwork, I can't see the proper result. All the command would point to single file webroot/index.php

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND         
23689 user  20   0 96168 1828 1296 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/app/webroot/index.php
```

mainly due to CakePHP framework will go through webroot/index.php before any other controllers script.

Is there anyway I can check which CakePHP models or controllers is consuming high CPU usage individually?

Comment: Are you using Apache for your webserver? Is so, the Apache `server-status` will show you the full URI for each current request. That's how we do it.

Comment: Not sure if this can help you out but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551401/cakephp-1-3-high-cpu-usage?rq=1

Comment: @jszobody yes I am using Apache.

Comment: @neobie Do you have this setup and enabled? It's super helpful: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html